# Rails dynamic layout selection and editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, layout, dynamic

I want to create a section in my admin interface where a layout can be edited. For instance, if the main layout is edited, I want this to be reflected across all pages. I could theoretically have each layout in the database and run it that way, but that is an extra database lookup each time a view is requested. Instead, I'd like to be able to edit the template file directly and have it saved. I am aware this is outside of the public directory, so how would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use sessions for temporary storage.

You may find this gem useful:

[dynamic_liquid_templates](https://github.com/akitaonrails/dynamic_liquid_templates)

Basically the template is chosen based on a controller instance variable, which you can always set from the session store to avoid database lookup.